In which condition given function will be inner product.
Let $\langle x, y\rangle $ be an inner product for $\Bbb R^n$ and the function
$\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1\colon\Bbb R^{2n}\times\Bbb R^{2n}\to\Bbb R$ is defined as follows
$$\langle x, y\rangle _1:=
a\langle x_1,y_1\rangle+
b\langle x_1,y_2\rangle+
c\langle x_2,y_1\rangle+
d\langle x_2,y_2\rangle$$
where $x = (x_1, x_2), y = (y_1, y_2)\in\Bbb R^{2n}$.
Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ so that the above defined function $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_1$ is an inner product for $\Bbb R^{2n}$.
I though just writing inner product conditions get equations and get some equalities. So one condition is to check on symmetry,
$$a\langle x_1,y_1\rangle+
b\langle x_1,y_2\rangle+
c\langle x_2,y_1\rangle+
d\langle x_2,y_2\rangle=
a\langle y_1,x_1\rangle+
b\langle y_1,x_2\rangle+
c\langle y_2,x_1\rangle+
d\langle y_2,x_2\rangle
$$
From here, I am getting that $b=c$. From other conditions, I can't get any useful information. Can you help?
Taking suggestions doing some edits.
$\langle x,x\rangle \geq 0$
$a\langle x_1,x_1\rangle  + b\langle x_1,x_2\rangle  +c\langle x_2,x_1\rangle  + d\langle x_2,x_2\rangle 
\geq 0$
Let's take $x_1=(1,0,\cdots) , x_2 = (0,1,\cdots)$ from here we get that $a+d \geq 0$

"From other conditions, I can't get any useful information": ? please show what you got.

Hint: $\langle x,x\rangle\ge0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R^{2n}$. Can you choose $x_1$ and $x_2$ in certain ways to conclude something about $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$?

We get $a+d \geq 0$?

No Hrant, that is not sufficient. Please edit your post to show your detailed attempts.

Updated, taking for example $x_1$ unit vector, $x_2$ 0 vector I get all coefficients are $\geq 0$

@HrantBaloyan: That is almost right. Can $a$ be $0$?

Probably not but cant think of why, is there any other condition that needs to be included also or is this enough?

@HrantBaloyan: What if $x=(e_1,e_2)$? ($e_i\in\Bbb R^n$ is the $i$th standard basis vector)

@ultralegend5385 I wrote that actually in my edited post don't we get a+d>=0?

@HrantBaloyan: My bad. What about $(e_1,0)$ and $(0,e_1)$?

Assuming that you are working on n-dimensional vector space over real/complex field, Let ${e_1}$, ${e_2}$, ...., ${e_n}$ be your standard basis vectors. For every positive definite matrix A, $$<x,y>:= x^*Ay$$ defines an inner product over $\Bbb{C}$ ($x^tAy$ for $\Bbb{R}$).
Conversely, any inner product on finite dimensional vector space over real/complex field can be realised as the quadratic form of a positive definite basis by fixing an orthonormal basis ${v_1}$, ${v_2}$ ..., ${v_n}$ and Set $A= [a_{ij}]_{{n}\times{n}} = <v_i,v_j>$. Now clearly $<x,y>=x^*Ay$ where x and y have coordinates wrt above basis.
In conclusion, for a finite dimensional vector space over real/ complex field, a function is an inner product if and only if it is a quadratic form of a positive definite matrix.
P.s. Here, I assumed linearity of inner product in 2nd variable

Please use mathjax to format your answer
